# Populate input field based on popup input

Tags: javascript, input, popup, field

I have a simple form that accepts input from a popup form (the user clicks Contour): https://codepen.io/alabamarob/pen/JjGYVjr. The user selects how they would like their input number distributed across dates from a graphic representing skew.

What I'd like to do is populate the "Adjustments" text fields based on the selected distribution curve and ETC amount. For instance, if the user selects the first curve, whatever amount in the ETC amount field would be distributed 10% 25% 65% and populate the adjustments fields accordingly. Likewise, the normal distribution would populate the 20% 60% 20% amounts.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!

````
//this is the main page
<table><tr><td>
<A HREF="skew.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')">Contour</a>
      </td>
     <td> <input name="0" type="text" />&nbsp;
    </td>
     <td> <input name="1" type="text" />&nbsp;
    </td>
     <td> <input name="2" type="text" />&nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
//this is the popup page
<table>
<tr><td>Choose Countour: <input type="radio" name="skew0" value="neg">
<img src="imgs/0.jpg" width="20px"></td>

<td align="center"><input type="radio" name="skew0" value="pos">
<img src="imgs/1.jpg" width="20px"></td>

<td ><input type="radio" name="skew0" value="no">
 <img src="imgs/2.jpg" width="20px"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>ETC Total Value:</td><td colspan="2" align="right"> <input type="textbox" ></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="self.close()"></td></tr></table>```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copy()
{
if(document.getElementById('neg').checked) {
 var n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
  var n3 = document.getElementById("n3");
  var n4 = document.getElementById("n4"); 
    n2.value = n1.value*.4;
  n3.value = n1.value*.5;
  n4.value = n1.value*.1;
}
   if(document.getElementById('pos').checked) {
  var n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
  var n3 = document.getElementById("n3");
  var n4 = document.getElementById("n4"); 
    n2.value = n1.value*.1;
  n3.value = n1.value*.7;
  n4.value = n1.value*.4;
} 
 if(document.getElementById('no').checked) {
  var n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
  var n3 = document.getElementById("n3");
  var n4 = document.getElementById("n4"); 
    n2.value = n1.value*.15;
  n3.value = n1.value*.7;
  n4.value = n1.value*.15;
} 
}
</script>
  <table border="0" style="background-color: #ffffff; filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity: 0.95;border:1px black solid;">
    <tr>
      <td>Enter ETC and Choose Contour: </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="n1" id="n1"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="skew0" id="pos"><img src="imgs/0.jpg" width="20px"></td>

<td align="center"><input type="radio" name="skew0" id="no"><img src="imgs/1.jpg" width="20px"></td>
<td ><input type="radio" name="skew0" id="neg">
 <img src="imgs/2.jpg" width="20px"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="copy();" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
  <table border="0"><tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>8/21/20</td>
    <td>9/25/20</td>
    <td>10/30/20</td>
    <td></td>    
    </tr>
   <tr> <td>Adjustments:</td><td><input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/></td><td><input type="text" name="n3" id="n3"/></td><td><input type="text" name="n4" id="n4"/></td><td></td></tr>
  </table>
```